# What are "hard" and "soft" consonants?

Tags: orthography, consonants

Many writing systems make a distinction between "hard" and "soft" phonemes represented by the same grapheme or an accented version thereof. What writing systems make this distinction and what are the consonants so distinguished?

Comment: "Hard" and "soft" consonants is an unofficial term which has different meanings in different languages. It can be palatalization (Russian), velar approximant (Turkish), or another phenomenon. Do you need a list of those?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK-ZbWcrKCk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the most widely-used non-technical non-literal terms employed to refer to a technical concept. As a general term it most often refers to palatalized consonants in Slavic (soft) versus not-palatalized (hard). This underlies English usage where "soft" *c,g* refer to sibilant versions (cent, gentleman) as opposed to velar stop versions (car, gut). It is also used to refer to [voicing](http://www.dutchgrammar.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1360) in Dutch (hard is unvoiced), oral obstruent vs. nasal in [Tamil](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Tamil_Language/Letters#Consonants) but with a third category for oral sonorants. It has been used to refer to emphatic (pharyngealized) consonants in [Arabic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Arabic/Arabic_sounds#Letters_that_come_in_hard_and_soft_varieties). The adjective is applied to vowels (hard is back) [in Spanish](http://www.elearnspanishlanguage.com/pronunciation/vowels-hs.html) and [Swedish](http://blogs.transparent.com/swedish/swedish-pronunciation-hard-and-soft-vowels/); in [Dinka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faucalized_voice), it refers to creaky phonation (also termed "harsh").

Comment: @Anixx How could [s] be both "hard" and "soft"?

Comment: In English, "hard" refers to pronunciation of letters, and isn't about phonemes. Actually, most usages are about letters, and it's only due to English having annoying spelling that letters and phonemes are out of sync. "City" and "cent" are examples of the exact same thing.