# Soft consonants in Devanagari

Tags: sanskrit, devanagari

Can someone tell me what are the soft consonants in Devanagari?

This [link](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/essentials-alphabet-alphabet-english-1/670) gives me a list of the devanagari soft consonants. However, is this the complete list? I find in other sources another list. Can someone definitively tell me what are the soft consonants in Devanagari

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about some external web page and this question becomes totally void when the link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consonants that your link calls "hard" and "soft" are now usually called "voiceless" and "voiced" respectively. This is the standard terminology in modern linguistics.

Answer (score 2):

"Soft" is not a meaningful linguistic term, though it may be used for various idiosyncratic purposes in a given language (e.g. in Slavic, soft consonants are palatalized. See [this discussion](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/19180/6726). Tamil consonants are classed as [hard, soft and medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_phonology#Consonants). This split is invoked in Monier Wiliams' [Practical Grammaar](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.319510023542503;view=1up;seq=26) p. 14, and seems to refer to *ghoṣavant*, i.e. "voiced" sounds.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit Image]

*Edit*: Added an image...

As a Hindi speaker myself (which uses Devanagari alphabet) I can *definitively* tell you that the link has all of the *soft* consonants. Do tell me if you are confused by any other links and attach the hyperlinks (as you mentioned).

Comment: In that chart य, र, ल, and व are not labeled as 'soft', but they are voiced. Does the term 'soft' refer to these consonants too?

Comment: य is the first consonant sound in _yellow_ (yak, yum etc.) र is _r_ (royal, ring etc.) ल is the second consonant sound in _yellow_ (linguistics, link etc.) and व is more or less _v_ (violin, van etc.) I am not quite sure if IPA lists these sounds as voiced and voiceless.

Comment: They are all voiced.

Comment: Then you probably found your answer!